# How to sort the list of files and projects in Kile

Tags: pdftex, kile

When I work in Kile, I like to have multiple (> 20) files open so that I can c/p equations between them, etc. To overview what's open, I always have File & Projects selected in the left sidebar. However, the list of the files appear unsorted (= sorted by some criterion that makes no sense to me). I'd like to sort them either by the time of access or by the filename. Is there a way to do that? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Is there a support for kile? Have you asked there?

Comment: I'm not 100% positive, but I don't think there is. You might ask about it on the [kile forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/kile/discussion/292014/) or open an issue about on the [KDE bugtracker](https://bugs.kde.org/).

Comment: Thanks! I will repeat the question there.